# Is there a formal way of stating "to be appointed"?

Tags: formality, business-language

I am currently writing the annual report for a charity. There are trustees which will be appointed, but not at the date of the report.

Is there a formal way of stating Trustee "to be appointed". It could also be that there is a latin phrase instead (such as, in other contexts, 'pro bono' or 'ex gratia')

Comment: There is nothing informal about the phrase *will be appointed*.

Comment: True, I'm just trying to make the report a bit more highbrow :)

Comment: "Prospective trustees" might work in this context.

Comment: Trustees-to-be?

Comment: They are already named as trustees, but not yet managing the trust, right?

Comment: Trustee-elect, like president-elect, but that's if they are elected trustees. If instead of being elected, they are appointed by somebody or a committee, then this may not be appropriate, though.